# Javascript How do I make this script compatible with IE8 and below using attach event

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8

How can I get the following to work in IE8? I assume from other threads I use an if else statement. Just not sure of the form it should take

Thanks in advance

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() { 
    var captions = document.getElementsByClassName("block1");
    var newlabel = document.getElementsByClassName("block2");
    for (var i = 0, c=captions.length; c>i; i++) {
       captions[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    for (var i = 0, n=newlabel.length; n>i; i++) {
        newlabel[i].style.display = "none";
    }

})();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are four issues to deal with:

1. Removing the incorrect `()` at the end (even when not using IE8).

   Solution: Just remove them.
2. Using `attachEvent` instead of `addEventListener` when necessary.

   Solution: Don't use an event at all, or detect which you have.
3. Dealing with the fact IE8 doesn't have `DOMContentLoaded`.

   Solution: Put the script at the end of the HTML rather than using an event. Or use `window.load`, but that happens really late.
4. Dealing with the fact IE8 doesn't have `getElementsByClassName`.

   Solution: Use `querySelectorAll` instead, which IE8 *does* have.

Again, the easiest way to deal with #2 and #3 is to simply put that code in a script tag at the very end of the document, just before the closing `</body>` element. Then you don't have to use an event at all, just run the code; the elements will be there and ready for scripting:

```
<!-- content... -->
<script>
(function() {
    var i, c, n;
    var captions = document.querySelectorAll(".block1");
    var newlabel = document.querySelectorAll(".block2");
    for (i = 0, c = captions.length; c > i; i++) {
        captions[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    for (i = 0, n = newlabel.length; n > i; i++) {
        newlabel[i].style.display = "none";
    }
})();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

If you really want to make it event based, then:

```
function handler() {
    var i, c, n;
    var captions = document.querySelectorAll(".block1");
    var newlabel = document.querySelectorAll(".block2");
    for (i = 0, c = captions.length; c > i; i++) {
        captions[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    for (i = 0, n = newlabel.length; n > i; i++) {
        newlabel[i].style.display = "none";
    }
}
if (document.addEventListener) {
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", handler);
}
else if (window.attachEvent) {
    window.attachEvent("onload", handler);
}
```

(Note that in both cases, I declared `i`, `c`, and `n` just once, at the top of the function. That's what your code did anyway, because of [how `var` works](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/poor-misunderstood-var.html), so...)

Comment: Thanks for such a speedy response. The event based script worked best as there are lots of other js elements and lazy loading going on in the page and the CMS does not give me the option of where to add the script.